# How to filter with custom field on customer grid Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, customer, collection, customer-grid

I have created a custom field in the filter on the customer grid using `customer_listing.xml`.

Now, the issue is

- **How can I filter with the custom field?** **Where do I need to do the operation?**

Please share the code with details so I can do them perfectly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what is that custom field ?

Answer (score 1):

In your `customer_listing.xml`

```
    <column name="custom_column" class="NameSpace\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\CustomColumn">
        <settings>
            <filter>text</filter>
            <label translate="true">Custom Title</label>
            <visible>false</visible>
        </settings>
    </column>
```

Now your `NameSpace\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\CustomColumn` class:

```
<?php

namespace NameSpace\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
use \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;

class CustomColumn extends Column
{
    protected $_searchCriteria;

    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $criteria,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = [])
    {
        $this->_searchCriteria  = $criteria;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$items) {
                $arr = []; //add data
                $customerId  = $items["entity_id"]);

                //your logic goes here
                ////    
                $items['custom_column'] = implode(', ', $arr);
                unset($arr);
            }
        }
        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

**I hope this helps you.**

Comment: this will not working with sorting or filter

Answer (score -1):

If it's a customer custom attributes, then you can easily set the attribute parameters `is_visible_in_grid` and `is_filterable_in_grid` or you can manually update the table `customer_eav_attribute` in the database and set these columns to `1`